# Unable to parse data using ajax in phonegap

Tags: javascript, ajax, cordova

I want to parse some data from server using ajax:
projects.js:

```
$("#Projects").click(function(){
        $.ajax({
           url: "http://192.168.0.49:1080/plw6.2/admin/OPX2ADMIN/192.168.0.49:9400/odata/project?%24select=name%2Cstatus",
           type: "GET",
           dataType: 'json',
        //Success of Authorization
        success: function(result){
          var tr;
          var str = JSON.stringify(result);
          obj = JSON.parse(str);
          for(var i = 0; i < obj.value.length; i++) {
            tr = $('<tr/>');
            tr.append("<tr><td class=\"project_title\">" + obj.value[0].name + "</td></tr>");
            tr.append("<tr><td class=\"project_status\">" + obj.value[0].status + "</td></tr>");
            tr.append("<tr><td class=\"project_date\">" + obj.value[0].real_start + "</td></tr>");
            $('.project_info').append(tr);
          }
        },
          //Failure of authorization
            error: function(jqXHR, status, errorThrown) {
                alert("error");

            }
     });
     });
```

Projects.html:

```
  <div class="project_info">
  <table>
                <tbody>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="project_title">Project1</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="project_status">Active</td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td class="project_date">03/2017-05/2018</td>
                  </tr>
                </tbody>
              </table>
  </div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./js/projects.js"></script>
```

I can't get the data from the server however the path of the server is correct.How can I fix that?

Comment: Does the console give you any feedback? What does the request look like and what's the response? Also, where's your Projects-ID in the html?

Comment: @Coss I got the alert error

Answer (score 0):

What data is returned from server? Put console.log( result ) into success()

You need allow PhoneGap to access external servers using allow-intent params... see https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/

---

So... your HTML table isn't correct (no have table /table)

Comment: Please, replace alert by console.log( jqXHR ), console.log( status ) and console.log( errorThrown )... this way will help you know what is happening.